# Error handling using ctype.h (C++)

Tags: c++, ctype

I've discovered the usage of library in C++ which is

```
ctype.h
```

I have an user input which is a string to accept words and is doing error handling using `ispunct()` to not accept punctuations. But I want `ispunct()` to accept " ' ".  Is there anyway for me to set the the parameter to skip " ' "?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have `ispunct` return false on a `'` character.  You can just write a custom wrapper to it if this is the case.

```
int myispunct(int c) {
    return c == '\'' ? 0 : ispunct(c);
}
```

Which first checks to see if `c` is a `'`.  If it is, it returns 0, otherwise it passes `c` to `ispunct` and returns from that.

Comment: Well, that would be lots of work. Thanks for pointing it out. I now try with your method and my method to compare.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, since `'\''` is punctuation, and that's what `ispunct()` looks for. You can check the characters manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{    
    if ( std::ispunct(word,loc) && word != "\'"  )
        throw string("Punctuations other then \' are not allowed!");
}
catch(string ex)
{
    //error handling
}
```

where `word` is your string.